# Mongodb Cluster Preimage Preferences by Collection re-enables itself mongodb 6.0

Tags: mongodb, triggers, atlas

I have a 3 node replica set in mongo6.0 that has a few triggers. I previously was using pre-image in 2 of my triggers.

I have since removed the need for preimages within the triggers and refactored, redeployed and toggled them off. I have disabled the preimage for each of the 2 collections that were using it under my Linked Data Source - > Advanced -> Preimage Preferences by Collection MongoDB Altas GUI.

One of the 2 collections re-enables itself after a period of time (a few hours) and I can not seem to figure out why. Has anyone experienced this?

I have also tried to disable the preimage setting from mongosh with the same result.